# Android App Install Location

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I went through the documentation it says "To install app to external sd card we need to declare android:installLocation attribute in the  element, with a value of either "preferExternal" or "auto"."

"**Only If the external storage is full, the system will install it on the internal storage.**"
**But what if application size is bigger than combined available size of Internal and External storage?
How to handle such situation?**

For reference:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

*The objective to confirm what exactly will happen and is there any need to handle it or Android will take care of it on its own*

Comment: Well it won't fit and there's nothing you can do about it. Android doesn't come with a magic wand.

Comment: but this situation cant be ignored simply this way..I am trying to raise the scenario on emulator

Comment: You should get "Insufficient Storage" error. How to handle? Just cleanup some storage.

Comment: I also think what Shaiful commented. You can try to do a lightweight app and download all the resources connecting to a server. Then you can get the free space available on the external storage and notice to the user if it is full.

Comment: It's up to the operating system to tell you that your program won't fit, as with any system. Your app can't do it, because it can't run, because it can't fit.

Comment: Of course, the system manage it. But It is just an idea to reduce the probability, so if the system does not allow to install a ligweight app lower than a few MB then the user should really clean up his device :)

Answer (score 0):

The same scenario I created on my emulator and found that if internal + external storage is less than app size then notification is popped up as "Low on Space" and it redirects to application manager to make some space for application.
As @Shaiful said we don't need worry about it (confirmation was very necessary for me.. :-)  )
Just create some more space and try Installation again
Thanks All !

[image]

Comment: _"App size bigger than combined available size of Internal and External storage?"_ I highly doubt such an app would work well in Android. If you mean the app and it's support file - i.e. expansion files - then see this [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html). Anyway, expansion files tend to reside either on Google Play's servers or your own servers and you have methods in your app to pull down these expansion files to be used in your app (most Android games do this). Otherwise, let Android handle the space for you. No need for complication...

Comment: @Chuong you are right!! application is not going to be published on Play..any way..I have come to a conclusion of letting Android handle it :)